# Rails: How can I use a single Regular Expression rule for both the validation and the class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, dry

I'm trying to keep my code DRY.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, format { with: /\A[:alnum:]+\z/}

  def self.create_with_username(name)
    username = name.match(/\A[:alnum:]+\z/) if name
  end
end
```

I am duplicating the regular expression matching rule: `/\A[:alnum:]+\z/`

My question is how can I make `/\A[:alnum:]+\z/` DRY so that I can use it in both the validation and .match method? So far, I tried making a class method, but the validation doesn't seem to pick it up. And when I try to make it a constant, the .match method doesn't pick it up (maybe cause the .match method is inside a class method...)

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by dry?

Comment: @AvinashRaj DRY: Don't repeat yourself. I want to capture the regular expression rule into an object and use it for my validation, and my .match method

Comment: You should add some info about the problem that's stopping you "using it as expected", eg what error or unexpected result you get.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Thanks. I made some edits, hopefully it is more clear now

Comment: I don't know what your "self.create_with_username" method is supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the POSIX class inside a character class..

```
\A[[:alnum:]]+\z
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store format as either a constant or a class method, rather than a local variable:

```
#constant
USERNAME_FORMAT = /\A[:alnum:]+\z/  # <-- What I want to keep DRY

#class method
def self.username_format
  /\A[:alnum:]+\z/
end
```

then you can say (using the constant example)

```
validates :username, format { with: USERNAME_FORMAT}

def self.create_with_username(name)
  username = name.match(USERNAME_FORMAT) if name
end
```

Comment: Still, you need to use POSIX character classes inside bracket expressions.